# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 : Unable to create new sites in my site collection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution, event-handlers, database-attach

So I had originally upgraded an old WSS 3.0 site to SharePoint Foundation 2010 by the database attach method. Site worked fine for a couple months until now. Now we our unable to create new sites in our web application. When I go to create a new site it come up with this error:

"Specified argument was out of range of valid values
Correlation ID {bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9}"

Here is the log info regarding that correlation ID:

```
01/03/2014 10:46:24.16  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (POST:http://sharepoint-test:80/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx))   
01/03/2014 10:46:24.16  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (POST:http://sharepoint-test:80/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx)    bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:24.16  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.33  SPUCHostService.exe (0x05D8)                0x0ED4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72nz    Medium      Videntityinfo::isFreshToken reported failure.    
01/03/2014 10:46:25.35  SPUCHostService.exe (0x05D8)                0x0ED4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (EnsureListItemsData). Execution Time=9.9656     
01/03/2014 10:46:25.35  SPUCHostService.exe (0x05D8)                0x0ED4  SharePoint Foundation           Sandboxed Code Service          fe66    Medium       -  - Unable to load assembly group. The user assembly group provider threw an exception while trying to provide user assemblies for the specified assembly group. - Assembly group id: ", GroupId = "0CC77F1F9C8A405A83E98B753629F117-ZqW+pqJcN5T9Qgj7zCdw1Y1XTq9qxp7h2bshHXvzhvo="" - Inner Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 iIndex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.GetSolutionInfoFromGallery(Guid siteId, Guid solutionId, String solutionHash, String& fileName, String& hash, Byte[]& fileBytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeLightweightSolutionAssemblyGroupProvider.GetAssembliesInGroup(Guid siteId, String assemblyGroupI...  
01/03/2014 10:46:25.35* SPUCHostService.exe (0x05D8)                0x0ED4  SharePoint Foundation           Sandboxed Code Service          fe66    Medium      ...d)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAssemblyCacheManager.EnsureUserCodeAssemblyGroupIsCached(Guid siteId, SPUserCodeAssemblyGroupId userCodeAssemblyGroupId)    
01/03/2014 10:46:25.36  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Sandboxed Code Service          0000    High         - UserCodeExecutionProxy call failed. Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionPipelineFailedException: Unable to load assembly group. The user assembly group provider threw an exception while trying to provide user assemblies for the specified assembly group. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 iIndex)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.GetSolutionInfoFromGallery(Guid siteId, Guid solutionId, String solutionHash, String& fileName, String& hash, Byte[]& fileBytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeLightweightSolutionAssemblyGroupProvider.GetAssembliesInGroup(Guid siteId, String assemblyGroupId)     at Microsoft.Sh... bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.36* w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Sandboxed Code Service          0000    High        ...arePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAssemblyCacheManager.EnsureUserCodeAssemblyGroupIsCached(Guid siteId, SPUserCodeAssemblyGroupId userCodeAssemblyGroupId)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAssemblyCacheManager.EnsureUserCodeAssemblyGroupIsCached(Guid siteId, SPUserCodeAssemblyGroupId userCodeAssemblyGroupId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)     at System.Runtime.Re...  bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.36* w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Sandboxed Code Service          0000    High        ...moting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)   bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.38  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           General                         6875    Critical    Error loading and running event receiver EduSiteTemplates.WebEventReceiver.WebEventReceiver in EduSiteTemplates, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35. Additional information is below.  Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.  bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.38  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (EduSiteTemplates, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, EduSiteTemplates.WebEventReceiver.WebEventReceiver)). Execution Time=1171.7166    bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.38  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High        Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.    bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.38  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (Creating Web test). Execution Time=1184.4302   bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.38  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateWeb(String bstrUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, Boolean bCreateUniqueWeb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid& pgWebId, Guid& pgRootFolderId, Boolean bCreateSystemCatalogs) bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
01/03/2014 10:46:25.52  w3wp.exe (0x0DE0)                           0x0568  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (POST:http://sharepoint-test:80/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx)). Execution Time=1359.0717 bef004f8-ac52-4a31-9ad3-101afeaa80e9
```

I know it has something to do with a previous sandboxed solution which was deployed improperly because when the sandboxed solution service is turned off and I try to create a new site, it states that it needs to be on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this error is some leading towards your sandbox solutions, even though you removed it but its not properly removed and still the reference of that solutions still exist in the sites. You have to remove the references from site collection. here is tool from Code plex which will help you find and remove the orphan solution/features.
[FeatureAdmin](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/)

or [Sharepoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/)

Another thing you can do. redeploy the sandbox solution and activate on site collections then step by step remove it.first deactivate it from site settings and then delete it or use poewershell Uninstall-SPUserSolution and Remove-SPUserSolution.